# Microsoft Access: Query to find difference in data

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables, TableAPX and TableCRD. In both there are 3 columns PC, C, VAL

How can I write a query where I can find the differences between columns C and columns VAL. Column PC is the primary key and TableAPX is the source for TableCRD. The objective is to reconcile TableCRD to TableAPX

I am very new with Access.

Thanks

Comment: What query have you tried so far? Please show that you have attempted to solve the problems.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`Select APX.C, CRD.C 
 From TableAPX APX
    Inner Join TableCRD CRD on CRD.PC = APX.PC
 Where Apx.C <> CRD.C OR Apx.Val <> Crd.Val`

That's a generalized query, but it should give you an idea of what you might do.

Answer (score 0):

In query design view you have both tables with a join on the PC fields.  Then add all columns to display in the query.

You can run the query and see the fields side by side.

Then to have the query highlight differing values - you need to create a calculated field; this is done with an alias name followed by a formula.  In this case you might do

Cdiff: iif(Apx.C=CRD.C,0,1)

this iif will display a 0 when they are the same and a 1 when they differ